# How to add custom XAML member to a custom panel (like the Grid.RowDefinitions member of the Grid panel)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a custom panel:

```
public class DevicesPanel : Canvas { ... }
```

Being used like this:

```
<vc:DevicesPanel>
    ...
</vc:DevicesPanel>
```

How can I add a `XAML` property like `Grid.RowDefinitions` of the `Grid` panel? it can be used like this:

```
<vc:DevicesPanel>
    <vc:DevicesPanel.Data/>
    ...
</vc:DevicesPanel>
```

and like this too:

```
<vc:DevicesPanel>
    <vc:DevicesPanel.Data>
        ...
    </vc:DevicesPanel.Data>
    ...
</vc:DevicesPanel>
```

---

### Edit:

I tried this:

```
public class DevicesPanel : Canvas {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty XyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Xy", 
                typeof (IEnumerable<UIElement>),
                typeof (DevicesPanel),
                new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable<UIElement>)));

    public IEnumerable<UIElement> Xy {
        get { return (Collection<UIElement>)GetValue(XyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XyProperty, value); }
    }

    ...
}
```

But this doesn't compile (the error is on the `XAML` part):

```
<vc:DevicesPanel>
    <vc:DevicesPanel.Xy></vc:DevicesPanel.Xy>
    ...
<vc:DevicesPanel>
```

The errors are:

```
Property 'Xy' does not have a value.
The attachable property 'Xy' was not found in type 'DevicesPanel'.
The member "Xy" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

(also tried `Collection` instead of `IEnumerable`)

Comment: It would seem to me that `Data` isn't something that you would put in the UI. What type of "data" are you talking about?

Comment: @HighCore, columns, rows, flow-terminator, whatever...

Comment: Then all your classes should inherit a base class (like `DevicePanelData` for example) and you can put a `Collection<DevicePanelData>` DependencyProperty in the Panel class.

Comment: @HighCore - updated my question - it doesn't work

Comment: @HighCore - it appears that [`csteinmueller` below is right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21260060/587467) - from some reason it must be a `List`. I'm trying to understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Grid.RowDefinitions` simply is a public property, you can add this property to your `DevicesPanel` class.

```
// DevicesPanel.cs
public class DevicesPanel : Canvas
{
    public List<string> Data { get; set; }
}


// MainWindow.xaml
<wpfApplication1:DevicesPanel>
    <wpfApplication1:DevicesPanel.Data>
        <system:String>Item1</system:String>
        <system:String>Item2</system:String>
        <system:String>Item3</system:String>
    </wpfApplication1:DevicesPanel.Data>
</wpfApplication1:DevicesPanel>
```

Comment: In general it works, but that: `<wpfApplication1:DevicesPanel.Data/>` doesn't: "`Property 'Data' does not have a value`"

Comment: That means your have to assign at least 1 value. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907401(v=vs.90).aspx